# Compare multiple columns to check if columns are duplicate PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to compare multiple column with each other to find if the columns in a table have similar values or duplicate and each table has more then 200+ columns.

Is there are way to compare using loop in PostgreSQL?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  For further information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You can compare whole rows with a condition like `(tab1.*) = (tab2.*)`. For more, please provide more details.

Comment: its a single table that has multiple columns. the comparison should be one is to many for example 1:1,1:2,1:3,1:4...etc then again 2:3,2:4,2:5,2:6 and so on...first column compare with all 200 + columns and same type of exercise for 2nd column, 3rd column, 4th column like wise for all the columns ..